# Angular - Drag-And-Drop to upload an attachment

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

I'm working on an Angular app similar to Trello and I need to implement drag-and-drop functionality for customers to be able to upload an attachment.

The thing is that there is already an 'Attach" function (Without drag and drop) used from another component and I would need to implement the drag-and-drop in the same way as the other function works. (I need to adopt this 'add attachment' function for drag and drop)

Here is a photo explanation:
https://ibb.co/d5WcJfQ

I tried watching youtube videos and google-ing but I'm having a hard times implementing it correctly and as requested. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
// HTML OF ATTACH COMPONENT
<span>
 <a class="quiet-button js-attach">
      <label class="custom-file-upload">
             <input (change)="onFileChange($event)" type="file"/>
              Add Attachment...
         </label>
     </a>
```

```
//TS FUNCTION 'onFileChange" That I need to adopt for drag-and-drop.`

onFileChange(event){

let files = event.target.files;
if (files.length > 0) {
  let formData: FormData = new FormData();
  for (let file of files) {
    formData.append('fileName', file, file.name);
  }
  let file = files[0];
  let attachmentData = <AttachmentInsert>{
    FileName : file.name,
    Path : ${this.cardHierarchy.BoardGuid}/${this.cardHierarchy.ListGuid}/${this.cardHierarchy.CardGuid}/`,
    Extension : this.getExtension(file.name),
    CreatedBy : this.currentUser.IdMember,
    IdCard : this.idCard
  };
  this.cardService.addAttachment(attachmentData).subscribe(data =>{
      let attachment : Attachment = data;
      formData.append('filePath',attachment.Path);
      this.cardService.uploadDocument(formData).subscribe(res => {
        this.getAttachments();

      });
  });

}
```

Comment: Did my answer help at all? It's kinda complex, but the problem is also complex...

Comment: @miselking thanks man. Yes, your answer helped me to do this task, much appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a rough example of how you can achieve this. First, add drag and drop events in `html` file:

```
<div (dragover)="onDragOver($event)" (drop)="onDropSuccess($event)">
  <label class="custom-file-upload">
    <input (change)="onChange($event)" type="file"/>
    Add Attachment...
  </label>
</div>
```

Implementation:

```
onDragOver(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}

// From drag and drop
onDropSuccess(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.onFileChange(event.dataTransfer.files);    // notice the "dataTransfer" used instead of "target"
}

// From attachment link
onChange(event) {
    this.onFileChange(event.target.files);    // "target" is correct here
}

private onFileChange(files: File[]) {
    ...
}
```

To add the "processing" effect just create a variable and use it to add/remove the "processing" element:

```
processing: boolean;
...
private onFileChange(files: File[]) {
    this.processing = true;
    this.cardService.addAttachment(attachmentData).subscribe(data => {
        ...
        this.processing = false;
    });
}
```

and use it in `html` like this (the `div` will be displayed if `processing` class is set, and that will be only if `processing` variable is `true`):

```
<div class="progress" [class.processing]="processing">
  Processing...
</div>

<!-- in "css" -->
.progress {
  display: none;
}
.progress.processing {
  display: flex;    // or any way to display an element
}
```

I added a working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ny1ht5).

Hope this helps.